# How to groupby and join but retain original row in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to group a dataframe by a key. The key is repeated twice. I want to create a new dataframe with both amounts AND the sum of those amounts on a single row.

Here is my dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([["key1", 800, "sales"], 
                   ["key1", 600, "cost"], 
                   ["key2", 500, "sales"], 
                   ["key2", 250, "cost"]], 
                  columns=["key","amount","type"])
df

    key amount  type
0   key1    800 sales
1   key1    600 cost
2   key2    500 sales
3   key2    250 cost
```

Here is how I want the output to look:

```
    key     sales   cost    sum
0   key1    800     600     1400
1   key2    500     250     750
```

I have tried a simple groupby function which gets me the sum value, but I can't figure out a way to also show the original 2 values on the same line.

```
df2 = df.groupby("key").agg({"key": 'first', 
                             "amount": 'sum'})

df2

        key     amount
key     
key1    key1    1400
key2    key2    750
```

I also tried a left join to bring both dataframes together but the individual values are still split across 2 lines:

```
df2.merge(df, how = "left", left_index = True, right_on = "key")

    key         key_x      amount_x key_y   amount_y    type
0   key1        key1        1400    key1    800         sales
1   key1        key1        1400    key1    600         cost
2   key2        key2        750     key2    500         sales
3   key2        key2        750     key2    250         cost
```

Appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`pandas.DataFrame.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df2 = df.pivot(index='key', columns='type', values='amount')
df2['sum'] = df2.sum(1)
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
type  cost  sales   sum
key                    
key1   600    800  1400
key2   250    500   750
```